# How i can us xor encryption in matlab without getting a special character? Like $ or some unreadable □ by matlab?

Tags: matlab, encryption, binary, xor

Let us say i want to encrypt text says "hello world"
with key is '01011010' using XOR

I converted the text into binary using Dec2Bin function
Then reshape it in way which i can XOR it with the key
Than make the Key same length as the text
After the XOR i get some different binary value
When i convert this binary back to text i get special character
Different type that some of them can't even be read by matlab like this some kind □ other just like $
And because i get this special character, i can't do decryption! I get different word like ( hello õorld ) sometime when the text is longer i get \n which Ignores line!
How i can solve this?
How i can get only abc or some character that are not space or anything that can't be input into matlab?

Comment: Compare the binary input to your encryption with the binary output from your decryption.  Any difference will help you locate errors.  If the binaries match then check the text to binary and binary to text conversions for errors.

Comment: Thanks for your response, yes I did. The problem still exists. When we do the xor operation between the text and the key, we get an 8bit binary value consisting of a special character, for example the number char(13) is empty and has no Letter  (or formal) representation, neither on the keyboard nor in any other way, so matlab ignores it completely.. and I don't know how it is possible solve this problem

Comment: XOR encryption produces random seeming bytes, not text.  If you need text output then either convert the cyphertext bytes to [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64), which gives printable text, or else use an adaptation of [Vigenère](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vigenère_cipher) encryption to keep the cyphertext within the allowed character set.

Comment: Thank you very much rossum, I have searched for base36 and found a suitable solution for converting output values from xor to representable characters! God bless you